# I can't install dropbox client: Cannont open libatomic.so.1

Tags: dropbox

After using the installation tool from the main dropbox page on Ubuntu 18.04 - LTS (Bionic Beaver), I tried to start it using the dropbox launcher for the app and never started.

Then, I tried to install it for Ubuntu using what is explained in the Ubuntu main page: https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux.

The issue: When I launched the daemon through the terminal using `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` I got the following exception:

```
File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>
File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in   <module>
ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
!! dropbox: fatal python exception:
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7919, in main\n',
'  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7843, in main_startup\n',
'  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 942, in __init__\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 147, in make_default_file_system\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 99, in __init__\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 118, in _initialize_classes\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/sync_engine.pyc", line 276, in <module>\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/thin_adapter/in_proc.pyc", line 98, in <module>\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/wrapped_thin_client.pyc", line 26, in <module>\n', 
'  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>\n', 
'  File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in <module>\n', 
'ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'] (error 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After surfing the web, [I found](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installs-integrations/Dropbox-daemon-can-t-run-on-Linux-without-dependency/m-p/379093#M83053) that it's needed to install the library libatomic1 to make it work.

To install the library, you have to execute the following command:

```
sudo apt install libatomic1
```

After that, execute back the daemon, and it'll work correctly:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

**NOTE**: This library is installed with Google Chrome, so if you had have the browser installed in your system you wouldn't have seen the issue.

Comment: Instead of `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` you can just `dropbox start`