# Installation Problems: Dropbox -> Libatomic ->?

Tags: software-installation, dropbox

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and I am having trouble to install Dropbox under a completely fresh Ubuntu 18.04.

I had the same problem as described in this previous short question 
[I can't install dropbox client: Cannont open libatomic.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192704/i-cant-install-dropbox-client-cannont-open-libatomic-so-1)
i.e. dropbox required the library libatomic1.

Unfortunately, the commmand:

```
sudo apt install libatomic1
```

only leads to the following error:

```
$sudo apt install libatomic1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As suggested in the command, I ran:

```
sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texworks/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 42min 11s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 43min 16s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 41min 22s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

How do I fix this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you updated your software lists on available software? (ie. `sudo apt update`) a your error message gives *out-of-date* packages (*thus error is valid*) (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-8-base)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This leads to a weird comment about release files?

Comment: Your system has an incorrect time set; it's currently 6.5+ hours wrong - thus it's rejecting those packages as something is wrong...  *check your time & timezone*

Comment: I fixed the time and this solved all other problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is if you've updated your software lists on available software? (ie. `sudo apt update`) as your error message gives out-of-date packages (thus error is valid; ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-8-base)

*OP responded with errors during `apt update`*

The error message highlights an invalid time, ie.

> is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 42min 11s)

Your system has an incorrect time set; it's currently ~6.5 hours wrong - thus it's rejecting those packages as something is wrong... Check your time (& timezone)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime
or
[How can I change the date and time on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349763/how-can-i-change-the-date-and-time-on-ubuntu)

Comment: ps: I've usually marked these as problem went away, but this maybe more appropriate for this site. I'm happy to close/delete this.