# Why is dropbox not working on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: dropbox

I did not use my computer for a month. On starting Dropbox after opening it, it shows the following
[image: Could not start dropbox daemon]
On checking [the Dropbox site](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/system-requirements#linux) for system requirements
[image: System requirements]
[image]
[image]
[image]
So I went about checking all these requirements,
GTK
[image: went about checking]

Glibc also (ldd in ubuntu)
[image: glibc]

Libappindicator 12.10 or higher
[image: libappindicator]

Nautilus 3.10.1 or higher
[image: nautilius]

libatomic version check
[image: libatomic version check]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that one of my photos had the error of

> libatomic.so.1: can't open

Blah

[image: libatomic error detect]

[On searching for libatomic in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=libatomic) I found [answer1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198216/installation-problems-dropbox-libatomic). This was a question about failure to implement [answer2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192704/i-cant-install-dropbox-client-cannont-open-libatomic-so-1).

Anyway on running the following command (as in [answer2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192704/i-cant-install-dropbox-client-cannont-open-libatomic-so-1) )

> sudo apt install libatomic1

It was fixed. Dropbox GUI and CLI are working now.

Comment: I am going to wait and see if there is a deeper and insightful answer than mine.

Comment: Strangely answer2 (as above) mentions the following "NOTE: This library is installed with Google Chrome, so if you had have the browser installed in your system you wouldn't have seen the issue"    But I have installed google Chrome

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. In the future, you're more likely to get help if you copy and paste the text from the screen into your question.  I can't read those screenshots you posted even on my large display and most people won't take the trouble to click on a bunch of images to see if they can help. Note that a very large fraction of the images you posted are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I will fix the issue from here onwards @OrganicMarble. For now, clicking on the image zooms on it.